# What is asio::io_service?

Tags: c++, select, epoll, asio

I am studying asynchronous I/O. i knows about select(), poll(), and epoll().
What I'm curious about is asynchronous I/O when using boost::asio. as a result of investigation, io_service is used. Which one of select(), poll(), and epoll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asio::io_service is outdated.

In newer boost versions it is replaced by asio::io_context.

io_context (formly io_service) main purpose executing ansynchrounous operations for object in the asio library, for ex. socket, acceptor, etc, according [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html):

> ...Synchronous operations on I/O objects implicitly run the io_context
> object for an individual operation. The io_context functions run(),
> run_one(), run_for(), run_until(), poll() or poll_one() must be called
> for the io_context to perform asynchronous operations on behalf of a
> C++ program. Notification that an asynchronous operation has completed
> is delivered by invocation of the associated handler. Handlers are
> invoked only by a thread that is currently calling any overload of
> run(), run_one(), run_for(), run_until(), poll() or poll_one() for the
> io_context....

Bascially, you send the tasks to be executed to the io_context (async_... functions), and io_context is reponsible to execute those tasks ( probably on  thread or thread pool) and call the provided callback (=handler).

It normally uses internally some version of [task-stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing) for efficient task distribution on threads in a thread pool.

Comment: Do you use epoll() inside io_context?

Comment: I'm not sure about implementation details, but I would expect it to use the platform available notification system for socket io - for ex. epoll on linux, kqueue on osx and completition ports on win.